# Why do I need an 8 gauge cable for 40 amps at 220v?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to install a 220v circuit for 40 amps(on my 110v power), 8-3 copper wire is rated for 40 amps. However, isn't 40 amps at 220v actually 110v, 20 amps on each hot wire? (on the US split-phase power, that is) I may be misunderstanding something fundamentally, and please note I won't take a big risk, I'm just curious if I understand this correctly. Also sorry if I posted this in the wrong place, or asked the same question I couldn't find a question similar to mine.

UPDATE:
Thank you so much! I figured I probably misunderstood, I understand DC power pretty good, I must not quite understand AC completely then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it’s 40 amps on each wire. The current flows from one hot, through the loads, and out to the other hot and is the same current all of the way. You may be thinking of voltage. Each hot terminal is only 120. volts to neutral or ground. In theory, you could use insulation on the wires that is only rated for 120 volts but insulation is cheap.

Comment: The voltage between the neutral wire and either of the hot wires will be 120 V.  But, the voltage between the two hot wires will be 240 V.  The hot wires will be near each other, so the insulation needs to be rated for the higher voltage.

Comment: @mrog However, when the two wires are next to each other, they will be separated by two layers of insulation (one on each wire). None the less, plastic insulation is cheap so there’s little reason to skimp.

Comment: That's a good point.